# Spectral properties of finite metric sets

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, linear-algebra

Given a finite metric set $S=\{P_1,\dots,P_n\}$, one gets a real symmetric matrix $M=M(S)$
with rows and columns indexed by elements of $S$ by setting 
$M_{i,j}=d(P_i,P_j)$. 
It is easy to see that $M$ has at least one strictly positive and one strictly negative eigenvalue
if $S$ contains at least $2$ points. For metric sets of three points, the matrix $M$ has always
signature $(1,2)$ (one strictly positive and two strictly negative eigenvalues).
(This holds in fact for any symmetric $3\times 3$ matrix with zero diagonal 
and strictly positive off-diagonal coefficients.)
In particular, we have always at least two strictly negative eigenvalues if $n\geq 3$.

It seems quite difficult to have more than one strictly positive eigenvalue 
if $n$ is small (I have an example with $n=9$).

Given an integer $d\geq 2$, what is the smallest number $n=n(d)$ such that there exists a finite 
metric space $S$ with $n$ elements giving rise to a matrix $M$ having $d$ non-negative
eigenvalues?

So far, all I know is $3< n(2)\leq 9$.

Update: $n(2)=4$, realized by the metric space with two pairs of points $A,B$ and $C,D$ at distance $2$, all other distances between distinct points are $1$. (The corresponding matrix $M$ has eigenvalues $-2,-2,0,4$).

I have an example with five points having two strictly positive eigenvalues.

Other bounds: $n(3)\leq 6$ (my example has however $0$ as an eigenvalue and only for $n=7$ do I have an example with three strictly positive eigenvalues), $n(4)\leq 9$ and $n(5)\leq 12$.

Answer (score 4):

Here's an answer if you make a further assumption on your metric space: if $M$ is of *strictly negative type*, then it has $n-1$ negative eigenvalues, according to Lemma 3.6 of [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science?_ob=ArticleURL&_udi=B6V0R-3SYR1FX-1Y&_user=6325866&_coverDate=02%252F28%252F1998&_rdoc=1&_fmt=high&_orig=search&_origin=search&_sort=d&_docanchor=&view=c&_searchStrId=1644320421&_rerunOrigin=google&_acct=C000062818&_version=1&_urlVersion=0&_userid=6325866&md5=6196e789b73f81ad1889bea1ad6a58df&searchtype=a).  This condition means that
$$
\sum_{i,j} M_{ij} x_i x_j < 0
$$
whenever $\sum_i x_i = 0$ and the $x_i$ are not all $0$, and it holds, for example, if your metric space is a subset of Euclidean space.

Added: it's maybe worth adding (although it doesn't directly bear on your question) that if $M$ is just of negative type (only $\le$ holds in the inequality above), then Lemma 3.6 also shows that $M$ has exactly one positive eigenvalue.

NB: There's a statement about 4-point spaces in the abstract of that paper which appears to contradict your 4-point example.  The actual result (Proposition 6.1) includes an extra hypothesis that excludes that example.

Added, part 2: I realized I wrote the above in a way that emphasizes the wrong points.  Lemma 3.6 in that paper is of course trivial.  The real point is that the terminology *strictly negative type* is worth knowing, so that you can find out which metric spaces have that property (and subsets of Euclidean space are among such spaces).

Comment: More generally, another way to think about this is that if K is a positive definite matrix, then it can be viewed as encoding "similarities" between pairs of points. there's a natural induced distance metric that can be computed from K, and this distance metric is of negative type if and only if K is positive definite. This illustrates the negative eigenvalue matter quite clearly IMO. This post of mine explains things in more detail. http://geomblog.blogspot.com/2009/08/negative-type-distances-and-kernels.html

Comment: Thank you for these informations. It seems to me that there is no known example of subsets of points in a $CAT(0)$ space giving rise
to at least two non-negative eigenvalues.

Comment: @Suresh: negative type is actually a stronger property than that.  The matrix $M$ is of negative type if and only if the matrices $K_{i,j} = e^{-t M_{i,j}}$ are positive definite for every $t > 0$.

Comment: The link to `sciencedirect.com` is broken. I'm also unable to find any snapshot saved on the Wayback Machine.